# how to decrypt password in Symbols to String whit Crypto JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I have a password encrypt in symbols and i try to decrypt this using Crypto-JS but its not possible.
I use this code:

```js
function dec2(ciphertext, key) {
    var source = ciphertext;
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(source, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding });
    console.log("decrypted", decrypted);
    console.log("decrypted", decrypted.toString());
    console.log("decrypted", decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
}
```

The password I use is like this: í•L6˜9³Y½f.õ

And when I decrypt it in the console log you see:

**First console.log**: array of bytes

**Second console.log**: Base64

**Third console.log**: base64

If anyone can help me convert this to a string I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("decrypted", decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
```

String just needs to be encoded as Utf8